# Dynamic Table Names in SQL query in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net-2010, ms-access-2010

I am trying to find a way to dynamically determine/reference a table name based on a value in another table.

In concept this is what I want:

```
SELECT * FROM TTestCase 
WHERE TTestCase.ElementNo = (
    SELECT TControlTables.ControlTable from TControlTables 
WHERE TControlTables.MessageType in (
    SELECT TTestCaseParameter.MessageType 
    FROM TTestCaseParameter).ElementNo
```

The "**SELECT TControlTables.ControlTable from TControlTables 
WHERE TControlTables.MessageType in (SELECT TTestCaseParameter.MessageType FROM TTestCaseParameter**" is the query that determines which table's ElementNo should be compared with the TestCase.ElementNo.

Comment: Any reason why you do not wish to dynamically write the sql?

Comment: Hi Remou, I do want to dynamically write it, I just don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some very rough notes, you will get much better code here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand(v=vs.71).aspx. Hopefully, this will start you off.

```
    Dim tablename As String
    Dim cn As New OleDbConnection("connection here")
    cn.Open()
    Dim query = "SELECT TControlTables.ControlTable " _
              & "FROM TControlTables " _
              & "WHERE TControlTables.MessageType in (  " _
              & "SELECT TTestCaseParameter.MessageType " _
              & "FROM TTestCaseParameter)"

    Dim dc = New OleDbCommand(query, cn)
    Dim tname As OleDb.OleDbDataReader
    tname = dc.ExecuteReader

    If tname.HasRows Then
        tname.Read()
        tablename = tname("ControlTable")
        tname.Close()
        query = "SELECT * FROM TTestCase WHERE TTestCase.ElementNo = ( " _
              & "SELECT ElementNo FROM [" & tablename & "])"
        dc.CommandText = query
        Dim rows As OleDb.OleDbDataReader
        rows = dc.ExecuteReader

    End If
```